# NSButton color (Vibrant Dark) changes by itself

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, nsbutton, nsvisualeffectview

I have a problem with my buttons:

Buttons A and B look good with any connection (@IBOutlet):

[image]

Button B looks bad when is connected:

```
import Cocoa

class ButtonsC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var b: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

[image]

and if I connect the button A, button B looks nice and A looks bad

```
import Cocoa

class ButtonsC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var a: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet var b: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

[image]

How can I fix it? or what kind of code in my project may be causing that?

Comment: Can you post all the code in your `ButtonsC` view controller? You're probably modifying some property which is causing this behavior.

Comment: The class is empty, I posted all the code.

Comment: I replicated exactly what you have and don't see the problem...

Comment: I think the problem is the code in other class but is a big project and I can't find it. Or maybe it is a bug with Xcode GM.